# What is idea of bindings in spring boot rabbitmq?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I need to bind several exchanges with several routing keys to one single queue and be able to send messages by exchange and routing key and receive it by listening to queue by queue-name.

my code:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ExchangeConfig.class)
public class RabbitConfig {

    private final ExchangeConfig exchangeConfig;

    @Bean
    public List<Binding> bindings() {
        List<Binding> bindings = new ArrayList<>();
        exchangeConfig.getExchangesWithKeys()
                .forEach(exchangeWithKeys -> exchangeWithKeys.getRoutingKeys()
                        .forEach(key -> {
                            Exchange exchange = ExchangeBuilder.directExchange(exchangeWithKeys.getExchange()).build();
                            Queue queue = QueueBuilder.durable(exchangeConfig.getLogsQueue()).build();
                            Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange)
                                    .with(key).noargs();
                            bindings.add(binding);
                        }));
        return bindings;
    }
}
```

config:

```
spring:
  
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672

rabbitmq:
  exchanges-with-keys:
    - exchange: exchange1
      routing-keys: exchange1.live, exchange1.after
    - exchange: exchange2
      routing-keys: exchange2.live, exchange2.after
    - exchange: exchange3
      routing-keys: exchange3.live, exchange3.after
  logs-queue: log-messages_q
```

props:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rabbitmq")
public class ExchangeConfig {

    private String logsQueue;

    private List<ExchangeWithKeys> exchangesWithKeys;

    @Data
    public static class ExchangeWithKeys {
        private String exchange;
        private List<String> routingKeys;
    }
}
```

listener:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogsListener {

    private final LogMessageEventProcessor logMessageEventProcessor;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.logs-queue}")
    public void onLiveEvent(LogMessageEvent event) {
        log.info("Received log event message [{}]", event.getBody());
        logMessageEventProcessor.processLogMessageEvent(event);
    }
}
```

test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = LogsListenerTest.Initializer.class)
class LogsListenerTest {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @ClassRule
    private static final RabbitMQContainer container = new RabbitMQContainer("rabbitmq:3.7.25-management-alpine")
            .withExposedPorts(5672, 15672).withQueue("log-messages_q");
    @BeforeAll
    private static void startRabbit() {container.start();}

    @AfterAll
    private static void stopRabbit() {
        container.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        template.convertAndSend("exchange1", "exchange1.live", new LogMessageEvent());
        template.receiveAndConvert("log-messages_q");
    }

    public static class Initializer implements
            ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(@NotNull ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            val values = TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.rabbitmq.host=" + container.getContainerIpAddress(),
                    "spring.rabbitmq.port=" + container.getMappedPort(5672)
            );
            values.applyTo(configurableApplicationContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything above does not working.

So where should i put these bindings to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version are you using? The use of `List<Binding>` has been replaced by `Declarables`.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#collection-declaration

The documentation is a bit out of date, the admin `declareCollections` property was removed in 2.2.

Comment: Just change the bean definition return type to `Declarables`; the bindings therein will automatically be declared by Boot's admin - DEBUG logging will show the declaration activity.